# Running into segmentation fault for below code

Tags: c, if-statement, segmentation-fault, scanf, dev-c++

Hey Guys i need help in my school project program, It is a Combination of switch(), if()...else, if()....else if()... and any other construct that you need to have the correct output.

Program Specs:

In a certain company, salary increases are made as follow: 
Technical staff : 5% for people who worked for more than 10 years . 3% for others

 Administrative Staff:

- 6% for the people in the Accounting Department

  4% for people in the Marketing Department

  3% for the other

Other staff: 2% increase 

and here is my code, but every time i compile and run it get runtime Error.: Hope someone can help me , cause am new into programming and the due is tomorrow

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main (void) 
{
int currentsalary;
int yearsinservice;
int percent;
float newsalary;
char choice1 ,choice2;



printf("Current Salary: \n");
scanf("%d", &currentsalary);
printf("Staff Category: \n");
printf("T - technical \n");
printf("A - administrative \n");
printf("O - others \n");
printf("Enter the staff Category: \n");
scanf(" %c", choice1);

switch (choice1)
{
       case't':
       case'T': printf("No. of years in Service: ");
                scanf("%d", &yearsinservice);
            if (yearsinservice > 10)
{
                     percent = currentsalary*.05;
                     newsalary = currentsalary + percent;
                     printf("New Salary: %.2f", newsalary);
}
else
{
    percent = currentsalary*.03;
    newsalary = currentsalary + percent;
    printf("New Salary: %.2F", newsalary);
}
    break;

case'a':
case'A': printf("Department where the staff belongs:");
        printf("A - accounting\n");          
        printf("M - marketing\n");
        printf("O - others\n");
        printf("Choose the department:\n");
        scanf(" %c",&choice2);
               if (choice2 == 'a' || choice2 == 'A')
               {
                              percent = currentsalary*.06;
                              newsalary = currentsalary+percent;
                              printf("New Salary: %.2f", newsalary);
               }
               else if (choice2 == 'm' || choice2 == 'M');
               {
                    percent = currentsalary*.04;
                    newsalary = currentsalary+percent;
                    printf("New Salary: %.2f", newsalary);
               }
               else 
               {
                   percent = currentsalary*.03;
                   newsalary = salary+percent;
                   printf("New Salary; %.2f", newsalary);

               }

               break;
               case'o':
               case'O': percent = currentsalary*.02;
               newsalary = currentsalary + percent;
               printf("New Salary: %.2f",newsalary);
               break;
               default: printf("Wrong Input");
               getch();
               }    
               getch();   
               return 0;
               }
```

the result should same in the sample output1:
Current Salary: 15000

Staff Category:

T - technical

A - administrative

O - others

 Enter the staff Category: T

No. of years in Service: 11

 New Salary: 15750.00

Ouput2:
Current Salary: 20000

Staff Category:

T - technical

A - administrative

O - others

 Enter the staff Category: A

Department where the staff belong

A - accounting

M - marketing

O - Other

Choose the Department: A

 New salary: 21200.00

Ouput3:
Current Salary: 15000

Staff Category:

T - technical

A - administrative

O - others

 Enter the staff Category: O

New Salary: 15300.00

Comment: whts the runtime error?

Comment: i got error " syntax error before "else" "

Comment: Since when syntax errors are runtime ones?

Comment: It might help you figure out where there are syntax errors if your code were properly indented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have problem in this line

```
else if (choice2 == 'm' || choice2 == 'M');
                                          ^
```

remove semicolon `;` at the end

Answer (score 1):

As I can see

**Point 1:** (your *runtime* error)

```
 scanf(" %c", choice1);
```

should be

```
scanf(" %c", &choice1);
             ^
             |
        notice here
```

**Point 2:** (Your *syntax* error)

You've got an unwanted `;` after the `else if` condition in `case`A`:` block. Remove that.

Comment: @Andrew_Gramming yes. In case a, remove the ; after the else if statement.

Answer (score 0):

Your first error is that you are calling

```
scanf(" %c", choice1);
```

when you should be calling

```
scanf(" %c", &choice1);
             ^
             need the & here
```

You should add the `&` before the variables ( except for strings ).

Your next error would be

```
else if (choice2 == 'm' || choice2 == 'M');
                                          ^
                                         semicolon not needed
```

You left a semicolon at the end. Remove it.